# $\det(A)={\pm 1} \iff A\in\mathcal O_n(\Bbb R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, linear-groups

I realise $A\in\mathcal  O_n(\Bbb R) \iff AA^T= I_n$

Does this hold true? $\iff \det(A)={\pm 1}$

Or is it just $\implies \det(A)={\pm 1}$

Comment: This works if $n=1$, but you should be able to find counterexamples for $n=2$ and above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $A\in\mathcal  O_n(\Bbb R) \implies  \det(A)={\pm 1}$

Indeed, $AA^T= I_n \implies \det(A)^2=\det(A)\det(A^T)=\det(AA^T)=1$.

The converse is not true, even for diagonal matrices:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&\pm \dfrac1a\end{bmatrix}
$$
is not orthogonal but $\det(A)={\pm 1}$. The rows of $A$ are orthogonal but not orthonormal.

Comment: Orthogonal matrices should be called orthonormal matrices but it's too late to change that.

Answer (score 11):

Not every matrix with $\det(A)=\pm 1$ is orthogonal. For instance, the matrix
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix} $$
is not orthogonal.